# Election situation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In an election for the managing committee of a reputed club, the number of candidates contesting an election exceeds the number of members to be elected by $r$ (given that $r>0$). A voter can vote in $967$ ways to elect the managing committee by voting for at least $1$ of them, and can vote in $55$ different ways to elect $r-1$ candidates by voting in the same manner.

Find the number of candidates contesting the election and the number of candidates losing the election.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? How far did you get?

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: After some thought, I realized that number of members of the club=number of voters of club =number of candidates contesting for $n-r$ posts in managing committee. I can post detailed solution if post is reopened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought, I realized that number of members of the club=number of voters of club =number of candidates contesting for $n-r$ posts in managing committee.

Let $n$ be the number of candidates for $n-r$ vacancies.
Number of ways in which voter can vote for at least one vacancy is

$$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+....+\binom{n}{n-r}=967.......(1)$$

Also,

$$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+....+\binom{n}{r-1}=55$$
which is same as
$$\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-2}+\binom{n}{n-3}+....+\binom{n}{n-r+1}=55.......(2)$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+....+\binom{n}{n-r}+\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-2}+\binom{n}{n-3}+....+\binom{n}{n-r+1}=967+55$$

$$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+....+\binom{n}{n-r}+\binom{n}{n-r+1}+\binom{n}{n-r+2}+\binom{n}{n-r+3}+....+\binom{n}{n-1}=1022$$

$$2^n-2=1022$$
$$2^n=1024$$
$$n=10$$

Clearly,$$\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}=55$$

Thus $$r-1=2$$

$$r=3$$

So, number of candidates losing the election=**7**